# Set of Radio Buttons Which Submit the Form When Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a set of 10 **radio buttons** (e.g. in a 1 to 10 rating system) which, when you `click` one, submits the rating automatically. This is achieved via the following:

```
<td>
    <input type="radio" name="img_rating" value="1" onclick="document.goRate.submit();return false;">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="radio" name="img_rating" value="2" onclick="document.goRate.submit();return false;">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="radio" name="img_rating" value="3" onclick="document.goRate.submit();return false;">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="radio" name="img_rating" value="4" onclick="document.goRate.submit();return false;">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="radio" name="img_rating" value="5" onclick="document.goRate.submit();return false;">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="radio" name="img_rating" value="6" onclick="document.goRate.submit();return false;">               
</td>
<td>
    <input type="radio" name="img_rating" value="7" onclick="document.goRate.submit();return false;">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="radio" name="img_rating" value="8" onclick="document.goRate.submit();return false;">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="radio" name="img_rating" value="9" onclick="document.goRate.submit();return false;">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="radio" name="img_rating" value="10" onclick="document.goRate.submit();return false;">
</td>
```

Is there any way to do this is a way that requires less **code**?  Ideally there would some way so that I don't have to include the same `onclick` 10 times, but perhaps this is the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to, you could use jQuery. Because than it will look like this:

```
<form name="gotoRate" id="gotoRate">
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="img_rating">1
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="img_rating">2
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="img_rating">3
    <input type="radio" value="4" name="img_rating">4
    <input type="radio" value="5" name="img_rating">5
    <input type="radio" value="6" name="img_rating">6
    <input type="radio" value="7" name="img_rating">7
    <input type="radio" value="8" name="img_rating">8
    <input type="radio" value="9" name="img_rating">9
    <input type="radio" value="10" name="img_rating">10
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

and the jQuery part

```
$(function(){
   $("input:radio").change(
      function(){
         $("form#gotoRate").submit();
      }
   );
});
```